# How do variable types affect pointer arithmetic work in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm having trouble understanding pointer's arithmetic.

Let `int B=0, *p=&B, **V=&p` and `sizeof(int)=4, sizeof(*int)=8`

What does the instruction `(*V)[1]` do?
To me, what I see is that `(*V)[1]` is equivalent`*(*V+1)`, so what should happen is, we **dereference** V (which is a pointer to a pointer to an int) and sum 1 to the content of that variable, which is an address. That variable is a pointer and we're assuming `sizeof(*int)=8`, so in theory we should sum `1 * sizeof(*int)` (which is 8) to whatever address is stored in the pointer p to which the pointer V points.

The solution, however, says to sum 4 (`1 + sizeof(int)`). Is it wrong or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: I have. I have read a whole book on the topic and this is what I understood of it, hence why I'm asking if the solution is wrong

Comment: @P__J__: That is not helpful; it is rude.

Comment: @DuarteArribas I find myself confused by the question.  What do `W` and `N` have to do with anything? Consider removing those.

Comment: Is “**dereference** y” a typo? There is no `y` in the code. Do you mean `V`?

Comment: @MooingDuck yeah sorry, done

Comment: @EricPostpischil nice catch! All Y are probably a typo

Comment: This is clearly undefined behavior, and the compiler is allowed to do anything, including possibly crashing or displaying random numbers on the screen.  I assume you're ignoring the language specifics and asking about what the most likely resulting bytecode actually does under the covers?

Comment: @MooingDuck correct. Please ignore the bad syntax of the code.

Comment: It is not useful to say or think that the value of a variable of pointer type is (merely) "an address".  There is a target data type associated every pointer type, and those play an important role in interpreting pointer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you reference is correct.

The expression `*V` has type `int *`, so it points to an array of 1 or more `int`.  So because it points to an `int`, when pointer arithmetic happens the size of the datatype it point to (`sizeof(int)`, i.e. 4) is multiplied by the given value (1).  So if you were to print the values of `*V` and `*V + 1` you would see that they differ by 4.

There is however a problem with `(*V)[1]`, equivalently `*(*V + 1)`.  Since `*V` points to `B`, `*V + 1` points one element past `B`.  This is legal since a pointer can point to one element past the end of an array (or equivalently a single object which is treated as an array of size 1).  What is *not* legal however is to dereference that pointer.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

`(*V)[1]` is indeed equivalent to `*(*V+1)`.

Since `V` is `&p` (by initialization), `*V` is `p`. So we have `*(p+1)`.

Note that both `*V` and `p` have type `int *`. They point to an `int`, so `p+1` points to “the next” `int`.

Since `p` points to `B` (by initialization), and `B` is a single `int`, `p+1` points just past the end of `B` (where the “next int” would be if we had an array of `int` there instead of a single `int`).

This “just past the end of `B`” is allowed for a pointer, and it is the location your source refers to for the solution that `(*V)[1]` effectively adds four bytes to the location that `*V` points to.

However, while it is allowed to refer to one past the end of `B`, the C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to access an object there. `(*V+1)` is a defined pointer, but `*(*V+1)` is not a defined expression for an object at that location. Its behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: So is the size to be multiplied is the *content* of the variable and not the *type* of the variable?

Comment: @DuarteArribas: Pointer arithmetic operates in units of the pointed-to type. If a pointer points to `int`, increments are in units of `int`.